# How to make dictionary element top level variables

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to transform dynamic simple dictionary elements into variables.

For example from the following dictionary:

```yaml
vm:
  cpu: 4
  name: test
  ip: 10.10.10.10
```

I need to generate the following variables:

```
cpu
name
ip
```

which values contains the values from the dictionary, of course.

Knowing that the dictionary keys (here `cpu`, `name` and `ip`) are variables and unknown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a [`set_fact`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html) task, you can template both the key and value, so, combine this with a [`dict2items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists), to loop on all the keys of the dictionary `vm`, and you have your required behaviour.

Given:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    "{{ item.key }}": "{{ item.value }}"
  loop: "{{ vm | dict2items }}"
```

This will set the three top-level variables `cpu`, `name` and `ip` to their respective values.

---

Given the two tasks:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    "{{ item.key }}": "{{ item.value }}"
  loop: "{{ vm | dict2items }}"
  vars:
    vm:
      cpu: 4
      name: test
      ip: 10.10.10.10

- debug:
    msg: |-
      cpu: {{ cpu }}
      name: {{ name }}
      ip: {{ ip }}
```

This yields:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    cpu: 4
    name: test
    ip: 10.10.10.10
```